# Как сделать вывод из базы по пять изображений на строку?

Tags: php, mysql

Одним запросом нужно сделать вывод из базы изображений в два ряда по 5 фотографий. Вот фото для наглядности:

[image]

Comment: Просто так из интереса: структуру БД мона увидеть? А вообще можно получить от 10 до всех записей, а потом размещать в блоках.

Comment: В базе название сайта и картинка к нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первый вариант:** получаем все записи и сортируем в блоки по 5
**Второй вариант:** юзаем селект с лимитом 5 и через цикл в несколько раз вытаскиваем по 5 записей. ***Не лучший вариант.***
**Третий вариант:** учим SQL, PHP и что-нибудь про алгоритмы.
Почти (не) сомневаюсь что вы пользуетесь каким-нибудь фреймворком. Посмотрите его документацию, может там найдётся подходящий функционал.

Comment: В том-то и вопрос... как их сортировать в блоки по 5?)))))))))

Comment: Либо вопрос не корректен, либо ты не в курсе про циклы.

Comment: на примере покажи простом

Comment: for($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    mysql_result($query, $i);
    }
вот толчок тебе!

Comment: Зря, лучше бы он сам учился.

Comment: $query - Это что? сроки поджимают, сегодня надо сдать скрипт. есди вы знаете, скажите, как это делается. в падлу что ли? щас учиться времени нет

Comment: хм...а мне в падлу тебе написать :) меняйте свою форму общения

Comment: ок, ясно все с вами